# Using URL rewrite to add custom URL for custom post type

Tags: url-rewriting, slug, rewrite-rules

I'm using ACF to make a multilingual site. My custom post URLs must work both with and without `/en/` as prefix. E.g. `mysite.com/posttype/any-slug/` and `mysite.com/en/posttype/any-slug/` must display the same post.

I've tried using this rewrite rule in functions.php (and some variations of it), but have trouble getting it to work:

```
add_action('init', 'add_my_rule');

function add_my_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^en\/posttype\/[.+]$','index.php?pagename=$matches[1]','top');
}
```

I've noticed there's other questions with similar titles, but the cases seem to be different from this one.

Comment: Just to make sure, you know that if `mysite.com/posttype/any-slug/` and `mysite.com/en/posttype/any-slug/` display **both** the same content, you expose your site to duplicate content issue (SEO related), right? Unless you 301 redirect one to the other...

Comment: Yes, I'm changing locale based on the URL, and using ACF to display different content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pagename` assumes the `page` post type. You need to use the custom post type query var in your rule instead. Presumably you also want to detect that this is a request for `en`, you can add your own rewrite tag to store that, then add that to the rule:

```
add_action('init', 'add_my_rule');

function add_my_rule() {
    add_rewrite_tag('%my_language%', '([^&]+)');
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^en/posttype/([^/]*)?/?$',
        'index.php?posttype=$matches[1]&my_language=en',
        'top'
    );
}
```

Comment: Yes, this did it! Didn't need the rewrite tag, since I detect the '/en/' in the URL and set the locale from that. Do you know if there's any benefits of setting it with the rewrite tag method?